# Multipurpose furniture shapeshifts at inconvenient times, abandoned in attic

Tags: identification-request

I studied a novel/story around 1995/1997 while I was in 7th grade or so. I vaguely remember the storyline. But I am unable to get the name or author of the story. The storyline goes like this:

> Protagonist buys a multipurpose furniture which can be turned into an easy chair (recliner), ironing board and a ladder. He was very proud owning that and everything was going fine for quite some time. Later, the springs of this furniture gets into trouble and in the most unwanted time, the furniture will transform to the other one on its own. While he iron press his dress, it turns into a chair. While sitting on the chair, it turns into a table and so... This creates a lot of problems in his life. At the end, he laments, that piece of furniture is in his attic; even now, when some mouse run over it, he can hear the sound of that furniture changing from one form to another.

Do anyone recognize this storyline? If so, please let me know the name or author of this story. Much thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Literature! Please can you add some more details which might help to narrow the search - e.g. when did you read it (we don't know when you were in 7th grade), how old was the story, which language was it written in (and was it a translation?), was it set in the present or a sci-fi future, was it set in any real-world country, ... ?

Comment: I studied this in around 1995-97 time. The story, I suppose was a early 20th century one. British or American story.